# Is there a manual process to reseal TPM FDE keys based on current system measurements in Ubuntu 23.10?

Tags: encryption, snap, luks, 23.10, tpm

There are a couple similar questions out there, but here is what I'm trying to figure out... In Ubuntu 23.10, if you change the system config or firmware, then unsealing the TPM isn't going to work, and you'll be prompted to enter the recovery key forever more...

My question is, is there a command (or set of commands) to reseal the keys with the new configuration after a system configuration change? The recovery keys and hash data seem to live at /var/lib/snapd/device/fde, but I'm not sure if that is for the original system config or the modified system config.

Basically, I'm trying to find out what the commands are that the installer uses to set up TPM in the first place. I know the easy answer is RTFM, and if someone knows a place to look (preferably other than having to reverse engineer the installation image), I would really appreciate it. :)

Thank you!